# asp:Button OnClick appears to override RequiredFieldValidator

Tags: asp.net, webforms, requiredfieldvalidator

In asp.net webforms, I have a number of textfields on which I'd like to use the RequiredFieldValidator. In coding them up and testing them, they work beautifully right up to the point that I add an OnClick event to the submitting button. For example:

This works...

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="NameTextBox" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="First Name" ValidationGroup="NotifyMe" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="NameValidator" ControlToValidate="NameTextBox" ValidationGroup="NotifyMe" ErrorMessage="You must enter a name." Display="Dynamic" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="SubmitNotificationButton" Text="Let me know..." CssClass="das-link btn btn-default blightblue" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="NotifyMe" />
```

There is no OnClick tied to the asp:Button, so when it is clicked with an empty field, I get the expected error message. However, when I add an OnClick event, and the button is clicked, regardless of the contents of the NameTextBox, the validation does not happen, and execution of the code moves to the button's OnClick event in the codebehind.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="SubmitNotificationButton" Text="Let me know..." CssClass="das-link btn btn-default blightblue" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="NotifyMe" OnClick="NotifyButton_Click" />
```

The code above will fail. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is working just fine. Usually when a Validator does not work and a PostBack happens anyway, there is a javascript error. Press F12 and see what's happening in the browser console.

Comment: I assume you are referring to F12  Dev Tools in Chrome. There are no errors. The button's click event runs and redirects the user to a confirmation page.  We should never get there because the field is empty.  The RequiredFieldValitor is being bypassed by the OnClick of the button. With out the OnClick, when I activate the button, I get the validator's error message.

Comment: No resolution on this, and I'm baffled as to why the validator works without an OnClick event but fails with it. That said, I gave up on the Validator and coded up my own checking routines in the codebehind. It's not really what I wanted, but it will work and allow me to move forward with the project.